# Docker Airflow : Run Papermill from a different Container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, jupyter-notebook, airflow

Consider my `docker-compose` file below. And for the sake of the question, assume that the papermill operator is already installed. How do I trigger the notebooks in `notebook` service?

```
version: "3"
x-airflow-common: &airflow-common
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  environment: &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ""
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: "true"
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: "false"
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: "airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth"
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}"
  depends_on:
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"',
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: version
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: "true"
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: "true"
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}

  notebook:
    image: jupyter/scipy-notebook:ubuntu-20.04
    user: root
    environment:
      - JUPYTER_TOKEN=password
      - GRANT_SUDO=yes
      - NB_GID=100
      - NB_USER=jovyan
    volumes:
      - ./work:/home/jovyan/work
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    container_name: notebook

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I've figured out:

###### Folders structure:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── airflow
│       └── Dockerfile
├── dags
│       └── papermill_test.py
└── papermill
        ├── Dockerfile
        ├── environments
        │       ├── requirements.txt
        │       └── environments.yml
        ├── notebooks
        │       └── papermill.test.ipynb
        └── output
```

###### docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  build:
    context: ./airflow
    args:
      - DOCKER_UID=${DOCKER_UID-1000} # build args: DOCKER_UID=`id -u`
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw # run this on localhost: sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ./papermill/notebooks/:/opt/airflow/notebooks/
    - ./papermill/output/:/opt/airflow/output/
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}"
  depends_on:
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: version
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}

  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  papermill:
    build: ./papermill
    image: your_name/papermill
    volumes:
      - ./papermill/notebooks/:/opt/airflow/notebooks
      - ./papermill/output/:/opt/airflow/output/


volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

###### airflow/Dockerfile

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.1.3

USER root
# This fixes permission issues on linux.
# The airflow user should have the same UID as the user running docker on the host system.
# make build is adjust this value automatically
ARG DOCKER_UID
RUN \
    : "${DOCKER_UID:?Build argument DOCKER_UID needs to be set and non-empty. Use 'make build' to set it automatically.}" \
    && usermod -u ${DOCKER_UID} airflow \
    && find / -path /proc -prune -o -user 50000 -exec chown -h airflow {} \; \
    && echo "Set airflow's uid to ${DOCKER_UID}"


RUN sudo addgroup --system docker
RUN sudo adduser airflow docker
RUN newgrp docker

USER airflow

RUN pip install apache-airflow-providers-docker
```

###### dags/papermill_test.py

```
from datetime import timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker import DockerOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from docker.types import Mount

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['your@email.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}
with DAG('papermill_test',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
         start_date=days_ago(2),
         catchup=False,
         ) as dag:
    run_this = DockerOperator(
        image='your_name/papermill:latest',
        task_id='docker_command',
        api_version='auto',
        auto_remove=True,
        command="papermill /opt/airflow/notebooks/papermill.test.ipynb /opt/airflow/output/papermill.test.ipynb -k papermill -p a 2 -p twice 5",
        docker_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock',
        network_mode='airflow_default',
        mount_tmp_dir=False,
        mounts=[Mount(target='/opt/airflow/notebooks/',
                      source='/<project_folder>/airflow/papermill/notebooks/',  # todo change it when in prod
                      type="bind"),
                Mount(target='/opt/airflow/data/',
                      source='/<project_folder>/airflow/papermill/data/',  # todo change it when in prod
                      type="bind"),
                Mount(target='/opt/airflow/output/',
                      source='/<project_folder>/airflow/papermill/output/',  # todo change it when in prod
                      type="bind"), ]
    )
```

###### papermill/Dockerfile

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:4.10.3-alpine

WORKDIR /opt/airflow/

# install environment
COPY ./environments/environment.yml environment.yml
COPY ./environments/requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN conda env create -f environment.yml
RUN . /root/.bashrc && \
    conda init bash && \
    conda activate papermill && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt && \
    python -m ipykernel install --user --name=papermill

RUN pip install ipykernel papermill

COPY ./notebooks /opt/airflow/notebooks
COPY ./output /opt/airflow/output
COPY ./data /opt/airflow/data

CMD ["papermill", "--help-notebook", "/opt/airflow/notebooks/papermill.test.ipynb"]
```

###### papermill/environments/requirements.txt

You can use the usual pip install -r requirements.txt file.

###### papermill/environments/environments.yml

```
name: papermill
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - tqdm
  - psycopg2
  - ipykernel
  - papermill
  - ipywidgets
prefix: /opt/airflow/envs/papermill
```

###### papermill/notebooks/papermill.test.ipynb

Here you can use the code in the example [here](https://papermill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage-parameterize.html#how-parameters-work).

###### Usage:

You can create new dags by using the code in the papermill_test.py file as a template. In order to execute papermill in the container remember to change the command parameter with the following:

```
command="papermill /opt/airflow/notebooks/name_of_your_notebook.ipynb /opt/airflow/output/output_notebook.ipynb -k papermill -p param1 1 -p param2 -p param3 3",
```

Don't forget to change permissions of the /var/run/docker.sock file from outside the docker containers with the following command:

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Unfortunately, I haven't found any other proper solution for this. I am open to proposals.